# Using URL with apalike style

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, urls

I'm writing my PhD thesis at this moment. I'm using apalike style since it does not have problems managing articles with many authors (plainnat and IEEEtranN have) but a big drawback is that it does not generate a clickable URL field (although one can use the howpublished to display the URL).

Does anyone know any style similar to apa (with text citation in parenthesis and using author name), that does not have problems with many authors per entry and that display an clickable URL?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**: Given the demand for proof that styles like IEEEtranN presented problems with multiple authors, here it is an example

tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Testing citation \cite{urmson2008autonomous}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@article{urmson2008autonomous,
    author = {Urmson, Chris and Anhalt, Joshua and Bagnell, Drew and Baker, Christopher and Bittner, Robert and Clark, M. N. and Dolan, John and Duggins, Dave and Galatali, Tugrul and Geyer, Chris and Gittleman, Michele and Harbaugh, Sam and Hebert, Martial and Howard, Thomas M. and Kolski, Sascha and Kelly, Alonzo and Likhachev, Maxim and McNaughton, Matt and Miller, Nick and Peterson, Kevin and Pilnick, Brian and Rajkumar, Raj and Rybski, Paul and Salesky, Bryan and Seo, Young-Woo and Singh, Sanjiv and Snider, Jarrod and Stentz, Anthony and Whittaker, William and Wolkowicki, Ziv and Ziglar, Jason and Bae, Hong and Brown, Thomas and Demitrish, Daniel and Litkouhi, Bakhtiar and Nickolaou, Jim and Sadekar, Varsha and Zhang, Wende and Struble, Joshua and Taylor, Michael and Darms, Michael and Ferguson, Dave},
    title = {Autonomous driving in urban environments: Boss and the Urban Challenge},
    journal = {Journal of Field Robotics},
    volume = {25},
    number = {8},
    pages = {425-466},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/rob.20255},
    url = {https://www.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rob.20255},
    eprint = {https://www.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/rob.20255},
    abstract = {Abstract Boss is an autonomous vehicle that uses on-board sensors (global positioning system, lasers, radars, and cameras) to track other vehicles, detect static obstacles, and localize itself relative to a road model. A three-layer planning system combines mission, behavioral, and motion planning to drive in urban environments. The mission planning layer considers which street to take to achieve a mission goal. The behavioral layer determines when to change lanes and precedence at intersections and performs error recovery maneuvers. The motion planning layer selects actions to avoid obstacles while making progress toward local goals. The system was developed from the ground up to address the requirements of the DARPA Urban Challenge using a spiral system development process with a heavy emphasis on regular, regressive system testing. During the National Qualification Event and the 85-km Urban Challenge Final Event, Boss demonstrated some of its capabilities, qualifying first and winning the challenge. © 2008 Wiley Periodicals, Inc.},
    year = {2008}
}
```

[image: PDF output]

Comment: If you want proper APA style see [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812). Related explanation: [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793). If what you mainly need an author-year style, then using the `ext-authoryear` style from `biblatex` is probably the simplest as it will do everything you want and is easy to tweak (which the proper APA compliant styles are not.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: The `apalike` is very old -- so old, in fact, that it pre-dates the creation of the Internet and the idea of using URLs to denote the online availability of some of the documents being cited. If you must use the `apalike` bib style, then place the URL informaiton in the `note` field, as in `note = {\url{...}}`.

Comment: Incidentally, I find your claim that the `plainnat` and `IEEEtranN` bib styles "have problems managing [entries] with many authors" rather dubious. I've *never* encountered any such problems. Please edit your posting to give a specific example of an entry that causes the `plainnat` and `IEEEtranN` bib styles to choke but works fine with the `apalike` bib style.

Comment: I tested with note = {\url{}} and it worked! But in the end I ended up using biblatex since it has more functionalities. Thanks.

Comment: `IEEEtranN` is supposed to be used together with `natbib`. I can reproduce the weird effect breaking in your MWE, but it goes away if you load `\usepackage{natbib}` (and the citation look much nicer).